# YUI 3.5 computed columns and sorting

Tags: javascript, yui

I am learning YUI 3.5 and I have computed the columns VAT and Total using formatters. (See jsfiddle below).

However sorting on them doesn't work. I guess because I am creating a visual representation for the data, but there isn't the underlying data under it. What is the proper way to create computed columns so that sorting works?

http://jsfiddle.net/zWk54/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a reply on IRC freenode #yui channel

```
<Tew> stivlo - http://jsfiddle.net/zWk54/2/  is how I'd do it.
<Tew> (using getter in recordType; just in case someone wants to comment on 
      that but is not tempted to click)
<Tew> stivlo - the examples are linked on top right-hand side,
      http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-recordtype.html 
     (Sortable generated columns).  In case you have some comment on 
     documentation, we(?)'d appreciate it (it's "that week", it seems).
```

Links: http://jsfiddle.net/zWk54/2/ and
       http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/datatable/datatable-recordtype.html